# What cards work with Esix, Fractal Bloom?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are a few different forms of templating that cards that generate multiple tokens use and I'm not sure how each works with [Esix, Fractal Bloom](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=518316).

1. *Generate `n` tokens*. Examples: [Saproling Migration](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443066), [Stolen by the Fae](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=473028), [Nest Invader](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=423494). Surely all of these effects work to create `n` copies of a permanent where `n` is the how many tokens they create.
2. *Generate `n` tokens then generate `m` tokens (same line of text)*. Examples: [Somberwald Beastmaster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=539139), [Specimen Collector](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=522140) [Tempt with Reflections](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376545). The question here is; are the tokens that are created separate instances of creating a token as far as Esix is concerned, or do I get to copy for each of these tokens?
3. *Generate `n` tokens then generate `m` tokens (different lines of text)*. Example: [Sylvan Offering](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430369). I'm not sure if this would be any different than #2 because it's on separate lines, so I figured I should check.
4. *Generate `n` tokens (as separate activations of the same ability)*. Examples: [Blaze Commando](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369047), [Poppet Stitcher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=534836). Surely these only allow you to make copies only on their *first* activation, even if multiple activations are on the stack at once.

There might be more ways to generate tokens that I haven't seen yet, but I think this covers most of it. I'm pretty confident about #1 and #4, but I'm not so sure about #2 and #3. The crux of the problem is what counts as a "time", so a link to the rules that govern what counts as a "time" for Esix (and other cards worded this way) would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To an extent, you have to use your own judgment when evaluating what counts as the same or separate events. The most relevant rule is [rule 700.1](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Additional_rules):

> Anything that happens in a game is an event. Multiple events may take place during the resolution of a spell or ability. The text of triggered abilities and replacement effects defines the event they’re looking for. **One “happening” may be treated as a single event by one ability and as multiple events by another.**

For an event like "you would create one or more tokens" as on Esix, the general rule is that a single instruction in a single sentence is one event, and multiple instructions are separate events. Line breaks within a spell don't matter here. They can make cards easier to read but they have no mechanical effect.

So, based on that rule, the cards you listed that create tokens in a single event are:

- [Saproling Migration](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Saproling%20Migration)
- [Stolen by the Fae](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stolen%20by%20the%20Fae)
- [Nest Intruder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nest%20Intruder) (which only creates one token anyway)
- [Somberwald Beastmaster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Somberwald%20Beastmaster)
- [Specimen Collector](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Specimen%20Collector)

The others have multiple separate events that create tokens. In particular, if an activated or triggered ability creates a token, then even if multiple instances of that ability can be on the stack at the same time, they resolve as entirely separate events.

One relevant ruling on [Tempt with Reflections](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tempt%20with%20Reflections) says

> After each opponent has decided, the effect happens simultaneously for each one who accepted the offer. Then, the effect happens again for you a number of times equal to the number of opponents who accepted.

Comment: So by that ruling Tempt with Reflections works right? If 3 opponents take the offer they all create their token first then I create 4 tokens which could enter as copies of anything on the board (assuming I haven't created any tokens yet this turn).

Comment: No, the card has three separate instructions. First you create one token. Then, each opponent may create a token. Finally, you might be able to create more tokens.